# How can I execute a task at regular intervals, but in a way so a step can't start until the last one has finished

Tags: java, concurrency

I have an agent-based model that I need to update every `t` milliseconds. In each update step, all the agent objects need to be notified and execute some code. I want every step to last `t` or until the last step has finished, whatever is longer.

How can I do this? I'm trying to use Timer.schedule, but it doesn't seem to be waiting because I'm getting a ConcurrentModificationException.

```
public void startClock(long delay) {

    Timer timer = new Timer("clock", true);
    TimerTask clockTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            World.INSTANCE.update(); //this updates all agents
            step++;
            for (Timed task : listeners) {
                task.run();
            }
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(clockTask, delay, interval); //miliseconds
}

public void startClock() {
    startClock(interval);
}
```

Comment: Can't you just have a boolean member variable that you check before executing the code in run()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleAtFixedRate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). It will execute your task either every `t` milliseconds or immediately after the last execution if it took longer than `t`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also evaluate [Akka Scheduler](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scheduler.html). It ensures that there will be no overlap of executions of the runnable. Here's the snippet from their documentation-

> If the execution of the runnable takes longer than the interval, the subsequent execution will start immediately after the prior one completes (there will be no overlap of executions of the runnable). In such cases, the actual execution interval will differ from the interval passed.